# Getting log4net to work

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I've wrote a wrapper class for using the loggers, and since I've never used log4net before (I use log4c++ at work, but it's already configured and I never needed to mess with it),
I don't know how to configure it properly and get it to work...

This is the current source code for the wrapping class:

```
using System.Text;
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Layout;

namespace GotLoggingService
{
    public sealed partial class LoggerManager
    {
        private ILog Logger { get; }

        #region Info Methods

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            Logger.Info(message);
        }

        public void InfoFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Logger.InfoFormat(format, args);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Debug Methods

        public void Debug(string message)
        {
            Logger.Debug(message);
        }

        public void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat(format, args);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Warn Methods

        public void Warn(string message)
        {
            Logger.Warn(message);
        }

        public void WarnFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Logger.WarnFormat(format, args);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Error Methods

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            Logger.Error(message);
        }

        public void ErrorFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Logger.ErrorFormat(format, args);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Fatal Methods

        public void Fatal(string message)
        {
            Logger.Fatal(message);
        }

        public void FatalFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Logger.FatalFormat(format, args);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Getters

        public static LoggerManager GetLogger(string name)
        {
            return new LoggerManager(name);
        }

        public static LoggerManager GetLogger(string name, LoggerManager parent)
        {
            return new LoggerManager(name, parent);
        }

        public static LoggerManager GetRootLogger()
        {
            return RootLooger;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    // Manage stuff here
    public sealed partial class LoggerManager
    {
        private const string FORMAT = "%timestamp  %-5level %logger %ndc - %ndc %message%newline";

        // Initializes root logger
        private LoggerManager()
        {
            Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
            BasicConfigurator.Configure(new FileAppender
            {
                AppendToFile = true,
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                File = "C:/log.txt",
                ImmediateFlush = true,
                Layout = new PatternLayout(FORMAT)
            });
        }

        private LoggerManager(string name) : this(name, GetRootLogger())
        {
        }

        private LoggerManager(string name, LoggerManager parent)
        {
            Logger = GetILog(name, parent);
        }

        private const string ROOT_LOGGER_NAME = "root";

        private static readonly LoggerManager RootLooger = new LoggerManager();

        private static ILog GetILog(string name, LoggerManager parent)
        {
            return LogManager.GetLogger(GetLoggerName(name, parent.Logger.Logger.Name));
        }

        private static string GetLoggerName(string name, string parent = ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
        {
            StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            nameBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}", LogManager.GetLogger(parent).Logger.Name, name);
            return nameBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried configuring with BasicConfigurator, supplying it with a FileAppender. I've tried logging stuff and it doesn't add anything to the file... Here's a short example of how I use the logger wrapper:

```
using GotLoggingService;

namespace trythelog
{
    class LoggerTry
    {
        private LoggerManager logger;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoggerTry logger = new LoggerTry();
        }

        public LoggerTry()
        {
            logger = LoggerManager.GetLogger("some-logger");
            logger.Info("this is a log message");
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically all I have to say... Thanks for reading and I would like it if you could point out stuff I messed up at.

I now use App.Config instead of BasicConfigurator

This is the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger %ndc - %ndc %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <file value="logs/" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger %ndc - %ndc %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I get this exception when I try to run : http://pastebin.com/qftQAHkn

```
ליו להיות הצאצא הראשון של אלמנט הבסיס <configuration>. (C:\GameOfThrowsUnityRepository\GameOfThrowsU
nity\GameOfThrowsServer\trythelog\bin\Debug\trythelog.exe.Config line 7)
   ב-  System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   ב-  System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors sch
emaErrors)
   ב-  System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   ב-  System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- סוף רכיב מעקב אחר מחסנית של מצב חריג פנימי ---
   ב-  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   ב-  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   ב-  log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key) ב- c:\log4net\tags\1.2.15RC1\src\Util\Syste
mInfo.cs:שורה 954
log4net:ERROR Failed to parse config file. Is the <configSections> specified as: <section name="log4
net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neut
ral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: אתחול מערכת התצורה נכשל. ---> System.Configuratio
n.ConfigurationErrorsException: אלמנט <configSections> אחד בלבד מותר לכל קובץ config ואם הוא קיים, ע
ליו להיות הצאצא הראשון של אלמנט הבסיס <configuration>. (C:\GameOfThrowsUnityRepository\GameOfThrowsU
nity\GameOfThrowsServer\trythelog\bin\Debug\trythelog.exe.Config line 7)
   ב-  System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   ב-  System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors sch
emaErrors)
   ב-  System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   ב-  System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- סוף רכיב מעקב אחר מחסנית של מצב חריג פנימי ---
   ב-  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   ב-  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   ב-  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.InternalConfigure(ILoggerRepository repository) ב- c:\log4net\
tags\1.2.15RC1\src\Config\XmlConfigurator.cs:שורה 173
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Sorry for the hebrew stuff :x

Comment: Why not use the configuration file?

Comment: How do I use it? I'm completely unfamiliar with configuring log4anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089286/correct-way-of-using-log4net or  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial

Comment: Use that codeproject link ^ it explains *everything* in complete detail and is a full tutorial on how to properly implement log4net.

Comment: <configSections> must  be the first child! Move up

Comment: Thanks @Mate! *no pun intended*

Comment: Great! Only remains to try other appenders . Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**Code**

```
using log4net;
...

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); // Missing!!?

            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
            log.Info("message");
```

**App.Config or Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>   <!-- must be the first child -->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>

   ...

  <log4net>
    <logger name="MyLogger">
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>


    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <file value="logs/" /> <!--YOUR PATH-->
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

  </log4net>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me the configuration you've given?

Comment: I guess the `logger` is the root logger, and basically I need to understand the appender settings. What is a `RollingFileAppender`? How does it set the file names? and so on. It sounds to me like it does something similar to `LogRotate`, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Pls, check all answers on my previous comment -> link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial . And yes, It's similiar to LogRotate. You can set file name <file value="myFile.txt" > or set a datePattern as in the example

Comment: @Mate You don't need XmlConfigurator if the configuration is provided in code itself which OP is doing.

Comment: @vendettamit check the first comments, It's a suggestion

Comment: @vendettamit, I switched to using app.config

Comment: @GioraGuttsait. Invalid config file... I guess. Edit your question and add your App.config. The idea is that you add these nodes to your existing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was caused by file property **Copy to Output Directory**. It was set to **Do Not Copy** (and it works for Web App) however, for Console App it must be set to **Copy always**

(use F4 key in Visual Studio to show Properties window)